# Average generates a negative decimal number

Tags: c, function, average

I created a function called average that will calculate the average age. How ever it is generating a strange negative decimal point.It was working fine until I put the strcmp function to people who have enter Texas. Example ages: 20 50 20 30 & 40 generate The average age is -243454739.00.
Can someone point me in the right direction, Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    //function decleration
    float average ( int A, int n);

    //int deleceration
    char names, states, statedata[100], namedata[100];
    int agedata[100], age, count = 0, A, n, avg;
    float a;

    //Get User Input 
    printf("Enter Number of family members being enter into program \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //Name Loop
    for (names=0; names<n; ++names)
    {
        printf("Enter Family members name:\n");
        scanf("%s", &namedata);

        //Age Loop
        for (age=0; age<1; ++age)
        {       
            printf("Enter family members age:\n");
            scanf("%d", &agedata[age]);
            A +=agedata[age];
            count= count + 1;

            //State Loop
            for (states=0; states<1; ++states)
            {
                printf("Enter Family members state:\n");
                scanf("%s", &statedata);

                //strcmp function for state name "Texas" Selection
                if (strcmp(statedata,"texas")==0)
                {
                    printf("Family members who live in texas\n");
                    printf("%s\n", namedata);   
                }           
            }               
        }
    }

    // Average function call
    a = average(A, n);
    printf("The average age is %.2f\n", a);

    return 0;   
}   

//A declarator
float average( int A, int  n){
   float average;
   average = A / n;
   return average;
}
```

Comment: Please endent your code. Better to read, easier to understand, fewer bugs ...

Answer (score 3):

Initialize `A` to `0` in `main()`. Uninitialized local variables have *indeterminate* values in C.

*Other issues:*

1)

```
scanf("%s", &namedata);
scanf("%s", &statedata);
```

Shoud be

```
scanf("%s", namedata);
scanf("%s", statedata);
```

Because `scanf()` expects a `char*` when for format specifier `%s` whereas you are passing `char(*)[100]`.

2)

All the values of *ages* are using type `int`. So the having the function `average()` return a `float` is still going to give an `int` result.
Change the type `A` (in `main()`) and the function parameter `A` (in `average()`) to `float`.

3)

Your inners are running `0..1` i.e. only once. So you don't really need those loops.

Comment: What is difference between both of your `scanf` statements in 1st point?

Comment: Fixed. Copy pasted the above lines and forgot to edit. Thanks!